# Meaning of "thwarting centuries of would be conquerors "

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

I got the following sentence from one of the GRE teaching websites. But I am not able to understand the bolded part in it.

> **Thwarting centuries of would be conquerors**, the Aztec fortress of
>   Chapultepec seemed impregnable, until U.S. forces under General
>   Winfield Scott were able to take the fortress with surprisingly little
>   effort.

Is the sentence as a whole grammatical?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alone, the bolded section would not be a proper sentence. Let me rephrase this sentence for you.

> The Aztec fortress of Chapultepec thwarted centuries of would be conquerors, and it seemed impregnable.

"Thwarting centuries of would be conquerors" is a phrase. This phrase has a verb, "Thwarting," but doesn't have a subject. But, when added to a sentence with a subject, this verb, "Thwarting," applies to the noun, "Chapultepec". So, "Chapultepec, thwarting centuries of would be conquerors, seemed impregnable." The main verb is "seemed." If we changed thwarting to thwarted, we could remove the commas and add an "and" between "conquerors" and "seemed".

In response to Edit:
Let's break down this sentence. First, we want to find the simplest sentence we can get:

"The Aztec fortress of Chapultepec seemed impregnable." This is a good sentence.

Now let us find the rest of the sentence. We now have a Dependent Clause:
"Until U.S. forces (prep. phrase) were able to take the fortress (prep. phrase)."

This is not a proper sentence. It is a dependent clause because of the Subordinating Conjunction, "Until." If we combine it with the first sentence, we get a proper sentence once again.

> Chapultepec seemed impregnable until U.S. Forces were able to take the fortress.

That sounds great. Now we add our phrase that tells us another thing Chapultepec was doing: "Thwarting centuries of would be conquerors."

Like I said, this states another thing the fortress was doing, but it isn't the main verb. If we add it to the original sentence, it still sounds fine.

> Thwarting conquerors, Chapultepec seemed impregnable until U.S. forces were able to take the fortress.

Comment: What does it mean by 'would be conquerors'?

Comment: I see. "Would be conquerors" says that some people would have been conquerors of Chapultepec. Let's rephrase the phrase.

"Thwarting people that would have been conquerors,"

Comment: Note that many authorities (such as the OED, and indeed myself), think *would-be* should be hyphenated in this sense. Also, pedants would say the sentence should start *Having thwarted centuries...*, though that would certainly be less effective.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply swap the present participle 'Thwarting' for 'Having thwarted'. Then the entire thing makes sense.